# call to library seems misleading

Tags: assembly, elf

In my disassemble binary (compiled with gcc -no-pie) file, I have following:

```
00000000004017e0 <strstr@plt>:
  4017e0:   ff 25 32 0a 64 00       jmpq   *0x640a32(%rip)        # a42218 <_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+0x218>
  4017e6:   68 40 00 00 00          pushq  $0x40
  4017eb:   e9 e0 fb ff ff          jmpq   4013d0 <_init+0x20>

Disassembly of section .plt.got:

00000000004017f0 <.plt.got>:
  4017f0:   ff 25 d2 07 64 00       jmpq   *0x6407d2(%rip)        # a41fc8 <_DYNAMIC+0x1d0>
  4017f6:   66 90                   xchg   %ax,%ax
  4017f8:   ff 25 da 07 64 00       jmpq   *0x6407da(%rip)        # a41fd8 <_DYNAMIC+0x1e0>
  4017fe:   66 90                   xchg   %ax,%ax
```

and later I have call:

```
403ab7: e8 3c dd ff ff          callq  4017f8 <strstr@plt+0x18>
```

The interesting elf header part could be:

```
Program Headers:
  Type           Offset             VirtAddr           PhysAddr
                 FileSiz            MemSiz              Flags  Align
  PHDR           0x0000000000000040 0x0000000000400040 0x0000000000400040
                 0x00000000000001f8 0x00000000000001f8  R E    8
  INTERP         0x0000000000000238 0x0000000000400238 0x0000000000400238
                 0x000000000000001c 0x000000000000001c  R      1
      [Requesting program interpreter: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2]
  LOAD           0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000400000 0x0000000000400000
                 0x000000000041b68c 0x000000000041b68c  R E    200000
  LOAD           0x000000000041c3e8 0x0000000000a1c3e8 0x0000000000a1c3e8
                 0x0000000000027868 0x00000000000df0b8  RW     200000
  DYNAMIC        0x0000000000441df8 0x0000000000a41df8 0x0000000000a41df8
                 0x00000000000001d0 0x00000000000001d0  RW     8
  NOTE           0x0000000000000254 0x0000000000400254 0x0000000000400254
                 0x0000000000000044 0x0000000000000044  R      4
  GNU_EH_FRAME   0x00000000003e2948 0x00000000007e2948 0x00000000007e2948
                 0x000000000000afd4 0x000000000000afd4  R      4
  GNU_STACK      0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000
                 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000  RW     10
  GNU_RELRO      0x000000000041c3e8 0x0000000000a1c3e8 0x0000000000a1c3e8
                 0x0000000000025c18 0x0000000000025c18  R      1
```

and

```
Relocation section '.rela.plt' at offset 0xd98 contains 65 entries:
  Offset          Info           Type           Sym. Value    Sym. Name + Addend
000000a42218  004300000007 R_X86_64_JUMP_SLO 0000000000000000 strstr@GLIBC_2.2.5 + 0
Relocation section '.rela.dyn' at offset 0xd08 contains 6 entries:
000000a41fd8  004a00000006 R_X86_64_GLOB_DAT 0000000000000000 strcmp@GLIBC_2.2.5 + 0
```

The question is how that instruction (callq  4017f8 ) worked here? This seems the call goes to .plt.got and then jump to someplace which is not in the relocation table. Can anyone explain it?

Comment: lazy dynamic linking updates the GOT entry that the PLT jumps through.  If you single-step in a debugger, you'll see the first call jumps back to the PLT entry, which calls the dynamic linker.   See http://www.macieira.org/blog/2012/01/sorry-state-of-dynamic-libraries-on-linux/ for more about how dynamic linking works.  (But note that recent gcc supports `-fno-plt` which does early binding and puts the indirect-call instructions inline instead of calling to the PLT wrapper.  More efficient and you don't have a writeable + executable page in your process.)

Comment: Surprisingly, I have found the following in my elf header:
Relocation section '.rela.dyn' at offset 0xd08 contains 6 entries:
000000a41fd8  004a00000006 R_X86_64_GLOB_DAT 0000000000000000 strcmp@GLIBC_2.2.5 + 0

a41fd8 is the target of the jump from .plt.got for my case. Why a strstr call jumps to strcmp?

Comment: glibc does runtime CPU detection for memcpy + string functions.  Perhaps that stub function sets up the pointers for multiple other functions?  Try single-stepping into it.